# send JSON object from Javascript to Flex

Tags: javascript, json, apache-flex

I am trying to send a JSON object from JavaScript to Flex and I am receiving "null",

Here is the code that I'm using for call the JavaScript method from flex:

```
private function checkUpdate():void {
    if (ExternalInterface.available) {

        var jsonObject:Object = ExternalInterface.call("getWhatsNew");

        Alert.show(jsonObject.toString()); //shows NULL
    }
}
```

And here is the java script code:

```
function getWhatsNew() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://10.76.116.54:8080/whatsnew',
    data: null,
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function (response) {
        return response;
    }
});
}
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Is it mandatory to use javascript to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you need to return something from your `getWhatsNew()` function.  Your code works out to be the same as this:

```
function getWhatsNew() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://10.76.116.54:8080/whatsnew',
        data: null,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function (response) {
            return response;
        }
    });
    return null;
}
```

You could get around this by adding the following to your SWF's initialization:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("receiveUpdate", receiveUpdate);
```

And your ajax "success" function:

```
success: function (response) {
    getSWF("whatsNewSWF").receiveUpdate(response); 
}
```

See the [Adobe documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cb1.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ca2) for more detail.